# Neo4j node name significance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

What is the significance of node name in Neo4j. What are the repercussions of making nodes without node name. Like the query

```
CREATE (:player {name: "Roger", YOB: 1985, POB: "Switzerland"})
```

has no node name?

Comment: Hi @ AnshulGupta, let me know if the answer I provided helped you to clarify about this subject. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The node "names" are actually variables. You can assign a node (or a relationship) to a variable to handle this node in the rest of the Cypher query. The [Neo4j docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/variables/) says that:

> When you reference parts of a pattern or a query, you do so by naming
>   them. The names you give the different parts are called variables.

For example, you can create a node and return it using a variable:

```
CREATE (node:player {name: "Roger", YOB: 1985, POB: "Switzerland"})
RETURN node
```

but if you are not referencing the node in the rest of the query has no necessity to assign it to a variable, in this case your Cypher example is fine.

Also, if you don't add a variable name, that the Cypher planner will automatically assign a unique variable name to the items you didn't. So the only repercussion for not using a variable name, is that you can't make explicit references to that item (Thanks to [@Tezra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6893866/tezra)).

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.Please if you also share the need to return the node name while creating a node.I understand in case of Match where we need to return specific property values.

Comment: Hi @AnshulGupta The `return` after `create` that I mentioned in my answer is only an example. There is not obligation to return a node after creation. Actually you can use variables to do any operation over nodes and relationships. For example, you can `MERGE` a node and `REMOVE` a given property using a variable. Like: `MERGE(node {id:1}) DELETE node.name`.

Comment: I would like to add, that if you don't add a variable name, that the Cypher planner will automatically assign a unique variable name to the items you didn't. So the only repercussion for not using a variable name, is that you can't make explicit references to that item.

Comment: Hi @Tezra, thanks for your contribution! Can I add your quote to my answer? Thanks!

Comment: @BrunoPeres yes, please do. :3 (Feel free to paraphrase if you have a cleaner way of saying it too =P)

Comment: @Tezra done! I think your phrase is clear enough! :) Thanks again!